# Split the cells, create columns, count

Tags: python, string, split, nlp

It's a multi-step exercise that, I suspect, can be handled in various ways. Here is what I have and have done.

tableA contains Stores and Brands. tableB contains Customer and Stores. Tables can be joined on Stores.

```
tableA = [(Ikea, 'Adidas, Nike'),
         (Target, 'Adidas, NB'),
         (Sears, 'Puma')]
labels = ['Store', 'Brand']
dfA = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tableA, columns=labels)

tableB = [('Neil', Ikea),
           ('Neil', Target),
           ('Javal', Target),
           ('Colleen', Ikea),
           ('Colleen', Sears),
           ('Javal', Target),
           ('Neil', Target),
           ('Colleen', Sears)]
labels = ['Customer', 'Store']
dfB = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tableB, columns=labels)
```

As an output, I want to have:
[image: Table]

Customers as rows, brands as columns and count as values.

First, I want to deal with splitting the cells and counting. Later, I will join two tables.

**Splitting**

The best I am able to achieve is:

```
dfA['Adidas'], dfA['Nike'] = dfA['tags'].str.split(', ').str
```

If I do:

```
dfA['Adidas'], dfA['Nike'], dfA['NB'], dfA['Puma'] = dfA['tags'].str.split(', ').str
```

I get a mistake:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

I understand the mistake's nature but haven't found an alternative yet.

**Questions I have:**

(1) Should I first deal with splitting and then join tables?

(2) How to properly split the column?

(3) How to add proper counts *(Counter has nothing to do with it, right?)*

Comment: I think you're missing one crucial piece of data: Brands purchased. You have the brands sold at each store, and the stores each customer purchased at, but nothing to say whether `('Neil', 'Ikea')` was 'adidas' or 'nike'

Comment: Once you get that part figured out, here's how you would for example, get the count of store visits by customer just for dfB using a `pivot_table` and count `dfB.pivot_table(index='Customer',columns='Store', aggfunc={'Store':'count'})`

Comment: @G.Anderson, it definitely helps! Seems that as soon as I'll be able to properly split the columns, I just run pivot_table once again and that's it.

Comment: @G.Anderson, regarding brands purchased. I don't think I need this data after I join two tables. The pivot table code you provided returns everything in the format I need. I just need to separate brands that are together and recount.

Comment: You can split the data and make new columns out of it like this `dfA=pd.concat([dfA,dfA['Brand'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1).drop('Brand', axis=1)`, but I don;t think it's going to get you want you want because each store only sells 1 or 2 brands

Comment: I would look instead at `str.contains` for all of your [string parsing needs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which uses the [splitting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) options which [@G. Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7835267/g-anderson) recommends along with [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.melt.html) to transpose the brands from columns to rows. The use of melt may be overkill/inappropriate, but this provides what seems to be the output you're looking to achieve.

```
import pandas as pd

tableA = [('Ikea', 'Adidas, Nike'),
          ('Target', 'Adidas, NB'),
          ('Sears', 'Puma')]
labels = ['Store', 'Brand']
dfA = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tableA, columns=labels)
tableB = [('Neil', 'Ikea'),
          ('Neil', 'Target'),
          ('Javal', 'Target'),
          ('Colleen', 'Ikea'),
          ('Colleen', 'Sears'),
          ('Javal', 'Target'),
          ('Neil', 'Target'),
          ('Colleen', 'Sears')]
labels = ['Customer', 'Store']
dfB = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tableB, columns=labels)

# split Brands into multiple columns
dfA = pd.concat([dfA['Store'], dfA['Brand'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)

# convert multiple columns to records using pd.melt
dfA = pd.melt(dfA, 'Store', var_name='Col', value_name='Brand').reset_index().drop(columns=['index', 'Col'])

# merge together frames A & B
merged = dfB.merge(dfA, on='Store')

# pivot data
pd.pivot_table(merged, index='Customer', columns='Brand', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

Here's a sample of the output.

```
        Store                  
Brand       NB  Nike Adidas Puma
Customer                        
Colleen      0     1      1    2
Javal        2     0      2    0
Neil         2     1      3    0
```

Comment: This works perfectly and achieves the goal! Voted up!